# ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I am learning how to make functions and triggers and I cannot get them to work. Here are all the relevant tables:

Table: "**cust**"

```
cust_id | email
------- | -----
1       | jack.daniels@google.com
2       | jose.quervo@yahoo.com
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com
```

Table: "**inv**"

```
fm_id | inv_id
----- |--------
22    | 10
23    | 11
24    | 12
25    | 13
26    | 14
27    | 15
28    | 16
29    | 17
30    | 18
31    | 19
31    | 20
32    | 21
```

Table: "**rent**"

```
inv_id | cust_id | rent_dt
------ |-------- | -------- 
10     | 1       | 9/1/2022 10:29
11     | 1       | 9/2/2022 18:16
12     | 1       | 9/2/2022 18:17
13     | 1       | 9/17/2022 17:34
14     | 1       | 9/19/2022 6:32
15     | 1       | 9/19/2022 6:33
16     | 3       | 9/1/2022 18:45
17     | 3       | 9/1/2022 18:46
18     | 3       | 9/2/2022 18:45
19     | 3       | 9/2/2022 18:46
20     | 3       | 9/17/2022 18:32
21     | 3       | 9/19/2022 22:12
10     | 2       | 9/19/2022 11:43
11     | 2       | 9/19/2022 11:42
```

Table: "**fm**"

```
fm_id | titl
----- | -----
22    | Anaconda
23    | Exorcist
24    | Philadelphia
25    | Quest
26    | Sweden
27    | Speed
28    | Nemo
29    | Zoolander
30    | Truman
31    | Patient
32    | Racer
```

Table: "**d_rpt**"

```
cust_id | email                     | fm_id | inv_id | rent_dt
------- | ------------------------- | ----- | ------ | --------
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 10    | 22     | 9/1/2022 10:29
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 11    | 23     | 9/2/2022 18:16
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 12    | 24     | 9/2/2022 18:17
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 13    | 25     | 9/17/2022 17:34
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 14    | 26     | 9/19/2022 6:32
1       | jack.daniels@google.com   | 15    | 27     | 9/19/2022 6:33
2       | jose.quervo@yahoo.com     | 10    | 22     | 9/19/2022 11:43
2       | jose.quervo@yahoo.com     | 11    | 23     | 9/19/2022 11:42
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 16    | 28     | 9/1/2022 18:45
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 17    | 29     | 9/1/2022 18:46
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 18    | 30     | 9/2/2022 18:45
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 19    | 31     | 9/2/2022 18:46
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 20    | 31     | 9/17/2022 18:32
3       | jim.beam@protonmail.com   | 21    | 32     | 9/19/2022 22:12
```

Table: "**sm_rpt**"

```
email                    | rd_cnt
------------------------ | ------ 
jack.daniels@google.com  | 6
jim.beam@protonmail.com  | 6
```

When a insert statement is run on the 'd_rpt' table the trigger should fire and run the truncate/insert/select statement for the the 'sm_rpt' table. Here are the trigger function and trigger statement:

**Trigger Function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ins_trig_func()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE FROM sm_rpt;
    INSERT INTO sm_rpt
    SELECT
    cust.email,
    count (DISTINCT inv.fm_id) AS "rd_cnt"
    FROM cust
    INNER JOIN rent ON rent.cust_id = cust.cust_id
    INNER JOIN inv ON inv.inv_id = rent.inv_id
    INNER JOIN fm ON fm.fm_id = inv.fm_id
    WHERE rent.rent_dt BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31'
    GROUP BY cust.email
    ORDER BY "rd_cnt" DESC;
END;
$$
```

**Trigger statement**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nw_wn
    AFTER INSERT
    ON d_rpt
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_trig_func();
```

I get success when creating both the trigger function and trigger statement from that. However when I go to test it out by truncating and then inserting new data, on the 'd_rpt' table, I get an error for the trigger and that is what I cannot solve. Here is that error:

```
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_trigger_function()
SQL state: 2F005
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

PS.
I did not include the truncate and insert commands that I use because I have already verified they work fine outside of trying to implement this trigger. The issue I think has to lie in the trigger function but the search feature and google are not my friend in trying to identify specifically what.

**

## EDITS To the above are found below here

**

OK, I have solved it now with both of your help. Thank you so much Belayer
and Adrian Klaver !!!!

```
CREATE FUNCTION ins_trig_func()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE FROM sm_rpt;
    INSERT INTO sm_rpt
    SELECT
    cust.email,
    count (DISTINCT inv.fm_id) AS "rd_cnt"
    FROM cust
    INNER JOIN rent ON rent.cust_id = cust.cust_id
    INNER JOIN inv ON inv.inv_id = rent.inv_id
    INNER JOIN fm ON fm.fm_id = inv.fm_id
    WHERE rent.rent_dt BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31'
    GROUP BY cust.email
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
```

Comment: A trigger function is *still a function* and must have a return statement. For an *After* trigger `return null;` will suffice.  Add that after your insert statement.  Also there is no need for `order by` in an insert statement. All rows in a table are unordered and even if ordered during insert that the ordering would not include existing rows (although is this case this immaterial due to truncate). It you later need deterministic sequencing you **must have** the order by on the `select`.

Comment: You need look no further then the docs [plgsql functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): *A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.*.

Comment: I apologize as my knowledge is limited (I'm a student) and I may not be understanding what you two are saying, but the trigger creation has a return in it, the second line of it is "RETURNS TRIGGER", is that not sufficient? If not, do I leave that line and add some unknown return thing somewhere else? Thank you.

Comment: PS... I also literally tried adding RETURN null; in the end of the insert statement after group by, and I tried adding it after the END; and I tried adding it after the $$ at the bottom. All those places resulted in an error. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN", LINE 17:   RETURN null;, SQL state: 42601, Character: 534.

Comment: New code and the resulting error, as suggested, appended to the bottom of my original post. Please advise how i should proceed?